# Stop traversing an RDD on a certain element

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a chronologically ordered sequence of elements and I want to scan it until a certain date/time can I stop Spark on a certain element? The filter transformation runs until the end of the sequence and it's not what I need.

Comment: The short answer is no you cannot do that. I also don't see why `filter` is a problem?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thank you for your help! Suppose I have a terabyte of data in reversed chronological order for a month. But I need to scan only the data for the last day. If I used the `filter`, Spark would scan whole the terabyte instead of first ~33GB.

Comment: Spark supports predicate push-down, meaning that if you do a `filter` operation right after your load your data, Spark will only store the relevant data in memory.